# How can I find the sum of the angle $AMB$, angle $ANB$ and the angle $ACB$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

How can I find the sum of the $\angle AMB, \angle ANB$ and the $\angle ACB$? In triangle $ABC$, $\angle ABC =90^\circ$. $BC$ is divided in $3$ parts such that $BM=BN=NC$. And also $AB=BM$.

[image]

Here are 2 of my attempts

prikachi.com/images.php?images/182/9546182c.jpg

prikachi.com/images.php?images/183/9546183U.jpg

But kinda messed up

I found their sum here prikachi.com/images.php?images/601/9546601o.jpg

But I really want to understand the Michael's method

Comment: Maybe you can draw a picture?

Comment: I am a New user and i dont have enough reputation.

Comment: http://prikachi.com/images.php?images/110/9546110k.jpg

Comment: @rucan1 There is a geometric solution of your problem. If you want to see this  solution, show us your attempts.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg Here are 2 of my attempts http://prikachi.com/images.php?images/182/9546182c.jpg http://prikachi.com/images.php?images/183/9546183U.jpg But kinda messed up

Comment: I opened it. See now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Delta CMK\cong \Delta NBA$ such that $A$ and $K$ placed in the different sides respect to $BC$.

Draw it in the  checkered page!

Thus, $AK=CK$, $$\measuredangle CKA=\beta+90^{\circ}-\beta=90^{\circ},$$
$$\gamma+\beta=\measuredangle ACK=45^{\circ}$$ and
$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=90^{\circ}.$$

Comment: Ok I understand but how prove that  ΔCMK≅ΔNBA

Comment: I found their sum here http://prikachi.com/images.php?images/601/9546601o.jpg But I really want to understand your method

Comment: @rucan1 Draw it in the checkered page! Нарисуйте этот треугольник на листочке в клеточку.                  שרטט את המשולש בדף משובץ

Answer (score 1):

Note that the angle $AMB=45^\circ$ because $AB=BM$.

For the rest, we see that $ANB=\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2}$ and $ACB=\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{3}$. 
Thus:
$$ANB+ACB=\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2}+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{3}=\tan^{-1}\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}}{1-\frac{1}{6}}=\tan^{-1}1=45^\circ.$$
Therefore the desired sum is $90^\circ$.

Comment: Thank you! And Also is there an easier way to be solved/explained for high school students.